# Compare two dates with a range

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime

is it possible to have something that can compare two dates in this format..
example today "Sep 30, 2013" and one week ago "Sep 22, 2013"
if its within this range say "good" if older then say "not good"
how can I make this in C# or vb.net

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: you can use `Subtract(DateTime)` to retrieve the difference in date and time from two given dates.

Comment: `yourDate >= startDate AndAlso yourDate <= endDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all users who helped me here.. this is the final code that I am using..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim fileDate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime("Sep 25, 2013")
    Dim rightNow As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"))
    Dim lastWeek = rightNow.AddDays(-7)

    If rightNow >= fileDate And lastWeek <= fileDate Then

        Debug.Print("its new")
    Else
        Debug.Print("too old")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If difference between dates is smaller than 7 days, it will print "good" otherwise "Not good"

```
var ok = (firstDate-secondDate).TotalDays < 7? "good": "Not good";
Console.WriteLine(ok);
```

`TotalDays` is `double` so you can check if differnce is in full days, use `Days` if you want completed days difference as `int`

Read more about [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) and it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(date1 >= Convert.ToDateTime("Sep 22, 2013") && date1 <= Convert.ToDateTime("Sep 30, 2013"))
{
good
}
else
{
bad
}
```

Comment: perfect but how can I get that Sep 22 automatically like -7 days?

Comment: replace the Sep 22, 2013 with Convert.ToDateTime("Sep 30, 2013").AddDays(-7)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic [Range](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html) class for checking some comparable value (like DateTime) falls into range:

```
public class Range<T>
    where T : IComparable
{
    public Range(T from, T to)
    {
        if (from.CompareTo(to) > 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("From should not be greater than To");

        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public T From { get; private set; }
    public T To { get; private set; }

    public bool Contains(T value)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(From) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(To) <= 0;
    }
    // other methods like Intersects etc
}
```

Usage:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var range = new Range<DateTime>(today.AddDays(-7), today);
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 9, 25);

if (range.Contains(date))
   // say good
```